# Apache Wicket exposes internal attributes

Tags: wicket

I just tried the Apache Wicket "Hello, world" application and I noticed that in the rendered HTML output, Wicket is exposing it's internal attributes.

This is what the rendered HTML looks like in the 'view source' of the browser:

```
<html>
<body>
    <span wicket:id="message" id="message">Hello World!</span>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get rid of the `wicket:id="message"` attribute in the rendered HTML output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Switch to [deployment](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/how-to-remove-wicket-markup-from-output.html) mode, e.g. in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>configuration</param-name>
 <param-value>deployment</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place below code in the init method if your applciation class

```
Application.get().getMarkupSettings().setStripWicketTags(true)
```

There was this one as well if not removed in the newer versions.

Comment: yep, see https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/how-to-remove-wicket-markup-from-output.html

Answer (score 1):

Also: this setting is configurable in runtime with:

```
Application.get().getMarkupSettings().setStripWicketTags(boolean)
```

Comment: You are wrong - you meant Application.get().getMarkupSettings().setStripWicketTags(boolean). Method setOutputComponentPath(boolean) do something else. It adds element attribute (wicket:path=....) with unique string which uniquely identifies the component (you can use this for automated tests) and at the same time you can read full component path/hieararchy with ease, which is good for debugging (hence this setting is inside IDebugSettings).